# How can I run .jar file on web page?

Tags: java, jar

I created my test.java as below;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"REG", "ADD", "HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main", "/v", "Start Page", "/d", "\"http://www.google.com/\"", "/f"});
            pb.start();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

compiled it to test.class and test.jar

Now I'm trying to run my jar file from webpage. Tried this applet code;

```
<applet code="test.class" archive="test.jar" width=120 height=120>
```

I'm getting this error;

[image]

How can I make it work correctly ?

Comment: You're going to have many issues on your way to getting this to work.  Once you actually write your code correctly, you'll have to sign your applet if you want it to be able to operate on the registry.  Your first goal should be to write an applet that says "Hello, World."

Answer (score 5):

Your class is not declared as an Applet.

Also the `main` method is the entry point for Java applications. Use `init()` for Applets:

```
// imports...

class test extends Applet {
    public void init() {
        try{
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"REG", "ADD", "HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main", "/v", "Start Page", "/d", "\"http://www.google.com/\"", "/f"});
            pb.start();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Applets need to be signed to operate outside their secured sandbox.

A more up-to-date approach is to run the Applet as a Swing application using [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html).

Comment: This answer only deals with one of the _many many_ issues you will have to solve before you get your applet to work.  You should start with something a lot more simple... Like an applet that says "Hello World."